# Angular console log source is always instrument.js

Tags: angular, google-chrome, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm now running Angular 12.1.0 in NX Monorepo in latest version 12.6.5. For a long time (not just with the last version) I noticed the console logs from angular components in my system are marked as comes from `instrument.js` file instead of real ts files.

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to investigate it and it does not happen in freshly generated NX repo.
I don't know where to focus my search. Webpack stuff is hidden behind Angular CLI. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 20):

**Fixed!**

Based on [this article](https://vandevliet.me/react-native-logs-coming-from-instrument-js-add-sentry-to-your-blackbox/) the problem is caused by Sentry javascript library.

Solution is to add sentry into ignore patterns in Chrome Devtools:
[image]